# Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'."

Tags: sql-server

Here is some part of my query:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'DestServer', @srvproduct = '', 
                        @provider = 'MSDASQL', @provstr = @MyProvider

DECLARE @TempStr NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @TempStr = N'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @DestDb + '.dbo.' + @DestTb 

EXECUTE DestServer.master.dbo.sp_executesql  @TempStr
```

But I get this error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DestServer" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.".

How can I fix it?

Comment: what kind of datatype is @DestDb and @DestTb?

Comment: sorry, '@DestDb' is nVARCHAR(100) and '@DestTb' is nVARCHAR(100)

Comment: Just a guess, can you try DECLARE '@TempStr' NVARCHAR(4000) to DECLARE '@TempStr' NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: I test that, but I get the same error (:

Comment: is it the sp_executesql statement that throws the error? maybe you should try to declare @TempStr as NVARCHAR(MAX)